# How do I get the execution plans for a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

How do I get the execution plans for a Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From SQL Server Management Studio check the 'Include Actual Execution Plan' option in the toolbar, then execute the procedure, see [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx)

**or** Run [`SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187757.aspx) then execute the procedure on the same connection, see [Displaying Execution Plans by Using the Showplan SET Options (Transact-SQL).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180765.aspx)

**or** capture the [Showplan XML Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189318.aspx) in the Profiler see [Displaying Execution Plans by Using SQL Server Profiler Event Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190233.aspx).

Comment: +1 Interesting, for anyone else looking for the Showplan XML Event, it can be found in the performance section

Comment: @Andomar: Profiler event plans are very usefull because is the only way to get the plan of a query run by an application *as it runs*. Capturing the SQL and then running from SSMS sometimes produces different plans.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: Exactly, we've seen that happen and it's really hard to troubleshoot.  We were able to resolve it with query hints like "loop join" and "with (index=)". The event class will be a useful tool when it happens next!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005, just type up the `EXEC YourProc` statement and hit `Ctrl-L`.

An alternative is to "edit" the stored proc by commenting out the SP definition parts, defining the parameters as local variables, and Displaying the Estimated Execution Plan (`Ctrl-L`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS Query Analyizer then there's a button you can click up on the tool bar.  If I remember correctly (MS QA not installed on this PC) then it looks like a speech bubble with some green or blue chart marks on it?